# The return type 'List<Menu>' isn't a 'Future<Menu>', as defined by the method 'anaMenuListeyiAl'

Tags: list, flutter, methods, future, defined

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/HzMF3ShspF/ i created this model class to get information from json data when page is loaded

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/hKmNTjFwkX/ this is my function to reach my data by using menuFromJson method but now it says

The return type 'List' isn't a 'Future', as defined by the method 'anaMenuListeyiAl'. What should i do i don't know, is there someone who can help me.

Comment: Please don't link externally to your code, you should insert it directly into your question - You should wrap it in ``` to format as a code block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things wrong here:
First, your method Future anaMenuListeyiAl() is a future that try to return a single menu an you want to make that return a list instead so change :

```
Future<Menu> anaMenuListeyiAl()async {
```

to

```
Future<List<Menu>> anaMenuListeyiAl()
```

Then, as i said, your method return a future so you have to await for it or use it in a futurebuilder.

```
List<Menu> menuList = await anaMenuListeyiAl();
```

or if in a initstate:

```
anaMenuListeyiAl().then((menuList){
 print(menuList);
});
```

**UPDATE CODE:**

This is the right function:

```
  Future<List<Menu>> anaMenuListeyiAl() async{
List<Menu> menuList;
final response = await http.post(
    global.apiUrl + global.anaMenuListe,
    headers: {"Content-type": "application/json"},
    body: json.decode({
      "key": "${global.key}", 
      "islem_kodu": "00X"
    }));
if(response.statusCode==200){
 menuList = menuFromJson(response.body);
}else{
 print("Unathorized");
}

return menuList;
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir, it works with local api so that i will try to use it tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

Sir, this time when i try to reach my method from the main page i can't reach to the variables
    islemDonus = IslemDonus();
    islemDonus.anaMenuListeyiAl().then((gelecekDeger){
      gelecekDeger.
    });